# jquery mobile checkbox list tap event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

In this code I cannot fire the tap or taphold event.

HTML

```
    <div data-role="content">
    <form>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>Vertical:</legend>
          <input name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
          <input name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
          <input name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c" type="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $('input:checkbox').bind( "tap", function() {
  alert("Test message");
  });
```

Here is a fiddle
 https://jsfiddle.net/frizzo28/jkfjrn0b/3/

Thank you

Comment: tap event not working for some css in JQM library... dont know xactly but this is the reason why JQM is the worst library I ve used... so I suggest dont use it... For now use click instead of tap or remove the jqm css file...

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I cannot remove jquery css because all the project is entirely based on this library. And i cannot use click because I need to bind both the tap and taphold function to do 2 different thing. Thank you davide